# Sorting a pandas dataframe by the subtraction of two values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been trying to sort a pandas dataframe by subtracting to values in the array and sorting the rows by the highest values that I get. For example, if I had the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
   "Data1": [1, 2],
   "Data2": [2, 3],
   "Data3": [5, 4],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I'd want to sort it and subtract Data3 and Data2 to become:

```
   Data1 Data2 Data3
1  1     2     5
2  2     3     4
```

Since `5-2 > 4-3`. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new column to do this

```
df['diff'] = df['Data3'] - df['Data2']

df.sort_values(by='diff', ascending=False)
```